# Set two flex items side by side in a flexbox column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have some elements I am displaying in a column direction within a `display: flex` container.

This places the containers within into a stacked view.

Say I have 5 stacked elements I need to make two of them display inline or flex direction row.

**Without placing the two elements in question into another div** that i can apply flex direction row to...

Is it possible to get these elements to sit side by side?

```css
.flex-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-column .column-item:nth-of-type(4),
.flex-column .column-item:nth-of-type(5) {
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.flex-column .column-item:nth-of-type(4) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-column">
  <div class="column-item">a</div>
  <div class="column-item">b</div>
  <div class="column-item">c</div>
  <div class="column-item">d</div>
  <div class="column-item">e</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't think it is possible once you have given your parent the `flex-direction:column;` property, alternatively you can enable `flex-wrap:wrap` and control the width of elements using the `flex-basis` property. This allows you to achieve the effect you want without altering your html structure.

```css
.flex-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.flex-column .column-item {
 flex-basis:100%;}
.flex-column .column-item:nth-of-type(4),
.flex-column .column-item:nth-of-type(5) {
    flex-basis:50%;
   
    
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-column">
    <div class="column-item">a</div>
    <div class="column-item">b</div>
    <div class="column-item">c</div>
    <div class="column-item">d</div>
    <div class="column-item">e</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16):

The layout is fairly simple with flexbox. You don't need `flex-direction: column`.

Just use `flex-direction: row` with `flex-wrap: wrap`.

Then make each element long enough to occupy a full row.

Reduce the `flex-basis` on the elements that are to share a row.

```css
.flex-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column-item {
  flex: 1 0 61%;  /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.column-item:nth-of-type(4),
.column-item:nth-of-type(5) {
  flex-basis: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-column">
  <div class="column-item">a</div>
  <div class="column-item">b</div>
  <div class="column-item">c</div>
  <div class="column-item">d</div>
  <div class="column-item">e</div>
</div>
```

With `flex-grow: 1` defined in the `flex` shorthand, there's no need to use `calc()`.

Since `flex-grow` will consume free space on the row, `flex-basis` only needs to be large enough to enforce a wrap. In this case, with `flex-basis: 61%`, there's plenty of space for the margins, but never enough space for a second item.

---

There's an even simpler and more efficient solution using CSS Grid:

```css
.flex-column {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.column-item:nth-of-type(-n + 3) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.column-item {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-column">
  <div class="column-item">a</div>
  <div class="column-item">b</div>
  <div class="column-item">c</div>
  <div class="column-item">d</div>
  <div class="column-item">e</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

```css
.flex-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;   
    
}
.column-item {

}
```

```html
<div class="flex-column">
    <div class="column-item">a</div>
    <div class="column-item">b</div>
    <div class="column-item">c</div>
    <div class="column-item">d</div>
    <div class="column-item">e</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No description, incorrect answer <3